# Android: Opening default phone dailing

Tags: java, android

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/header"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="127dp"
    android:text="@string/phone"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:typeface="sans" />
```

I have a test view which holds my phone information. How do i open an default phone dailing box on the click of the message.

```
<string name="email">Phone: 1-866-232-3805</string>
```

Here is my Override method.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView03);
            email.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                 public void onClick(View v) {
                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub                
                 }

           });
}
```

What should i do from here?

Comment: do you mean phones default dialer?

Comment: @juned: Yes onclicking the number, i need the phone dailer to open this number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first take the number from string.xml and then call `Intent.ACTION_DIAL` with the number.

```
String phone = getResources().getString(R.string.email).split(":")[1];
        Intent DialIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,Uri.parse("tel:"+phone));
        DialIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(DialIntent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code in onclicklistener of textview

```
 Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);

            callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+t2.getText()));
            startActivity(callIntent);
```

and also add the following permissions in your manifest file

```
 <
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to just open a dialer then

```
Button contactsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contacts_button);
        contactsButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                startActivity(myIntent);
            }
        });
```

if you want to open dialer with specified nunber then

```
Button contactsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.contacts_button);
        contactsButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +Call_number));
                startActivity(callIntent);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below intent which displays the CALL DIAL:

```
 Intent dial = new Intent();
 dial.setAction("android.intent.action.DIAL");
 dial.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ Phone));
 startActivity(dial);
```

where `Phone` is the Phonenumber which u want to call.